# Flex: Can List be used to display control in equally sized tiles

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

In one of the application I am working, List has been used. I am required to display items in the form of tiles. I do not want to change the component as of now. Is there any way to achieve this layout in list only.

Please let me know if you have any idea in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are not able to change the component, are you able to change the structure of the data provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the layout on your List to TileLayout.  And as alxx said, you may need to create a custom ItemRenderer and set that on your List as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make custom renderer and plug it into your list via itemRenderer property.

http://www.arpitonline.com/blog/2008/01/22/creating-custom-list-renderers-the-complete-guide-part-i/